# Manual mock for Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, mocking, rails-geocoder

How could I mock any method without using any gem?

Suppose I have access to an complex object like `request`

How could I make

```
request.location.country
```

to return a mocked value.

I read I can mock `geocoder` results with gems, but I would like to know a generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've been doing it

```
foo = Geocoder.search('Paris, TX')
foo.first.county
```

I'm using the BingAPI, and to figure out what options I can access on the `foo.first` object, I take a look at the Geocoder docs:

http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Bing

Answer (score 0):

As far as Ruby is a duck-typed language where the exact object type isn't verified AOT, then dependency injection is as simple as writing a class that has the same methods/signatures/return types as the real one.

For doing proper mocking, I've used [Flexmock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/) in the past with some success, but YMMV depending on what you're doing.